# Will the `npm whoami` command fail if the auth token is revoked?

Tags: npm, whoami

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsFLx.png)

As can be shown in the image attached, I set the auth token in the NPM registry and ran the `whoami` command. Will it throw a 401 error if the token has been revoked?

I want to know if the 401 error is thrown if the token has been revoked or if there's a better way to find that out

Comment: Please share all text content **in text form**, not hidden in screenshots